# Check that this is a category

Tags: category-theory, field-theory

Assume we have a fixed field $F$. We define objects as homomorphisms $\phi:F\rightarrow G$. Then we define morphisms between  $\phi:F\rightarrow G$ and $\psi:F\rightarrow L$ as ring homomorphism from $G$ to $L$.

How should I show that this indeed is a homomorphism. We did that during the classes and were talking about ideals in field, but since I don't have to much knowledge of algebra, I didn't understand much.

Thanks

Comment: What are G and L.  Your objects/morphisms aren't very clearly defined.

Comment: I suppose these are fields, we defined objects as field homomorphisms from F.

Comment: Looks like 'commacategory $\left(F\downarrow\mathbf{Fields}\right)$ Objects are arrows $\phi\in\mathbf{Fields}\left(F,G\right)$
and arrows from object $\phi$ to another object $\psi\in\mathbf{Fields}\left(F,L\right)$
are arrows $\tau\in\mathbf{Fields}\left(G,L\right)$ such that $\psi=\tau\circ\phi$. Since you talk about ringhomomorphisms from $G$ to $L$ it is not unthinkable that
you are dealing with commacategory $\left(F\downarrow\mathbf{Rings}\right)$